# React - Routing & Redirect after login to attempted page

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

What is best practice to implement react-router 4? Currently I created two components, `PrivateRoute` and `PublicRoute`. `PublicRoute` is for `/login` path and it renders `Login` component, and `PrivateRoute` is for rest of paths and it renders passed Component if user is logged or does redirect. `PrivateRoute` code is:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => (
<Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    helpers.getCurrentUser()
        ? (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <Sidebar/>
                <div id="content">
                    <Navbar/>
                    <Component {...props}/>
                    <Footer/>
                </div>
            </div>
        ) :
        <Redirect
            to={{
                pathname: "/login",
                state: {from: props.location}
            }}
        />
)}/>
```

);

And `Router` component in same file is:

```
export default () => (
<Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path={'/login'} component={PublicRoute}/>
        <PrivateRoute exact path={"/"} component={Dashboard}/>
        <PrivateRoute exact path={"/users"} component={UsersComponent}/>
        <PrivateRoute exact path={"/logs"} component={LogsComponent}/>
        <PrivateRoute exact path={"/project"} component={ProjectComponent}/>
        <PrivateRoute exact path={"/user"} component={UserComponent}/>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

);

How to implement redirection to attempted page if not logged?

Comment: You mean how to redirect the user to the attempted page after successful signin ?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are already passing the location from where you came as a location state to Redirect in PrivateRoute, you can use the same while redirecting back from Login component

In the login component you would have

```
onSuccessLogin = () => {
   const {location} = this.props;
   if(location.state && location.state.from) {
      this.props.history.push(location.state.from);
   } else {
      this.props.history.push('/');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use component's lifecycle method `componentDidUpdate` to handle route's updating as described in [react-router-4 migration guide](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/migrating.md#on-properties).

For example:

```
class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route path='*' component={RootRoute}/>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}

class RootRoute extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.object, // this prop comes from withRouter feature
    location: PropTypes.object, // this prop comes from withRouter feature
    user: PropTypes.object // this prop should come from your App
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.checkSession({
      location: this.props.location.pathname,
      user: this.props.user
    })
  }

  checkSession({location, user}) {
    if (!user.isLogged() && !user.isLocationPublic(location)) {
      this.props.history.push('/login')
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/login' component={LoginRoute}/>
          <Route path='/backoffice' component={BackOfficeRoute}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(RootRoute)
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the two answers above, this worked for me:

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    const {location} = this.props;
    if(location.state && location.state.from) {
      this.props.history.push(location.state.from.pathname);
    } else {
      this.props.history.push('/');
    }
  }
```

Don't do it in `componentDidUpdate` - it will be called continuously.